# How can I access the UITextLabel in a xib?

Tags: ios, uiview, properties, xib

I set a custom `MyView` as background view for a `UITableView`:

```
MyView *noCellsView = [[MyView alloc] init];
[[noCellsView messageLabel] setText:@".........."];
[[self tableView] setBackgroundView:noCellsView];
```

It is displayed as background view, but the `messageLabel` is not set.

Why is that?

**MyView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSObject *viewFromNib;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *messageLabel;
@end
```

**MyView.m**

```
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        UIView* xibView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [xibView setFrame:[self bounds]];
        [self addSubview:xibView];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**MyView.xib** 
The messageLabel is connected to the @property.

Comment: You did a `init` , but you overwrite `initWithFrame`

Comment: @Larme default UIView's -init calls -initWithFrame: with CGRectZero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you connect your outlets to `MyView` view in your nib but not to `file owner`. So that you end up with `MyView` view with another `MyView` as a subview. But the outlets are set only for the child `MyView`.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    ...
        // see that `owner:` parameter, it's the one who you want that `file owner` thing
        // to be, so if you'll bind outlets to file owner in xib and pass self to
        // this method for owner: parameter, you'll have outlets, binded to `file owner`
        // assigned to self.
        UIView* xibView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]; // outlets are assigned to xibView, but not to self
    ...
    [self addSubview:xibView];
    ...
}
```

To make it work, you could bind (in Interface Builder) outlets to a `file owner` instead of `MyView` view. But, that would be a mess (you have `MyView` with `MyView` as a subview and the first one is some kind of a redundant proxy for the child one) and I'd suggest you to just create some other method or load view directly via `-loadNibNamed:owner:options:`.

```
// example method
+ (instancetype)loadFromXib
{
    // make sure that for that case you leave outlets binded to `MyView`, not to `file owner`.
    MyView *myView = ... //load from xib
    return myView;
}

// ...
// later on:
MyView *noCellsView = [MyView loadFromXib]; // vs [[MyView alloc] init];
[[noCellsView messageLabel] setText:@".........."];
[[self tableView] setBackgroundView:noCellsView];
```

Comment: Thanks @Maniak_bobrii, what would I have to change to make it work?

Comment: Good answers are always appreciated